# Declaring a class field of same class type. C#

Tags: c#, class

If a class member having data type of the same class under which it is defined, what it means?

```
class Node
{
     int value;
     Node next;
} 

class LinkedList
{ 
      Node head = new Node();
}
```

What I understand is that 'head' is a instance variable which can hold two type of data integer and node type.

Comment: "'head' is a instance variable which can hold two type of data integer and node type." Yeap, and what´s your question? A node can have sub-nodes. Or if it is the last child, it doesn´t have any further sub-nodes making `text` being `null`.

Comment: It just means you've got a nested hierarchy.

Comment: it means a `Node` has two fields: one of type `int` and one of type `Node`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `text! null? Did you mean `next` ? Also, doesnt have to be null. It could be set to refer to itself, as a way of denoting "you've reached the end of the chain"

Answer (score 1):

> What I understand is that 'head' is a instance variable which can hold
>   two type of data integer and node type.

No, it is an instance of `Node` which has two fields, one `int` and one `Node`.

Of course a class can have a member of itself, so a `Node` can contain a property or field of type `Node`. That's useful if there is a relation, a chain. So for example one node can have a linked node.

Another example: a class `Human` could have a property `Human Father` and another `Human Mother`:

```
public class Human
{
    public Human Mother { get; set; }
    public Human Father { get; set; }
    public List<Human> Children { get; set; }
}
```

A class is just the definition, the blueprint. An instance of this class can have a different meaning. Therefore it's important to use meaningful names.